# Selenium IDE:After Recording the Application Functionalities in IDE,i use the tool to run.But,it is showing error like:

Tags: ide, selenium

[error] Element //div[@id='divProjects']/table/tbody/tr/td[6]/i not found

i tried to use xpather,firebug inorder to find the id's and values of the object.But,it is not working for me.

please help me to solve my issue.

Comment: if you didnt understand my query,please give me feedback.

Comment: Unless you provide the HTML as well, nobody can really answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can share the IDE script, it'll make easy to resolve the issue. You have to verify that you have got to the element when you are trying to perform any action on it.

Answer (score 0):

Your xpath needs to be more relative. One thing you can try is to change the xpath to xpath:relative while recording in IDE. You can find this option on clicking on the dropdown